# Woocommerce booking

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

Does anybody know how can change person type fields like this:[image: like this] ?

Currently it looks like this:
[image: Original]

thank you.

Comment: it's not clear.. can you describe in details ?

Comment: I want to move the fields beside each other @SumanBiswas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.wc-bookings-booking-form .form-field input[type=number] {
    width: 55%;
}
.wc-bookings-booking-form .form-field {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Although changing the 'field' view using CSS isn't recommended, you can copy & paste the above CSS in your style.css file and then click on **Update file** to save the changes. It'll shift the alignment from vertical to horizontal.

**Note:** You probably have to adjust the values(%) based on your website's page. Alternatively, you could use another [WooCommerce bookings plugin](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-booking-and-appointments/) to display the participants/people field in a better and more recommended way.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you but I try this before it's changed same [this](https://prnt.sc/qxqn10) and i used another plugin too they have many problems for my job :)